# How to trigger event when a radio button is checked in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried doing [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/zrNV5/59/).So, when I click on the radio button, the code works but the radio button doesn't get checked and it remains normal. How to solve this?

```
<p>
    <input id="play" class="rad" type='radio' name='a'/>
    <input id="pause" class="rad" type='radio' name='a'/>
</p>
```

```js
var output = $('h1');
var isPaused = false;
var time = 30;
var t = window.setInterval(function () {
    if (!isPaused) {
        time--;
        output.text("0:" + time);
    }
}, 1000);

//with jquery
$('.pause').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    isPaused = true;
});

$('.play').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    isPaused = false;
});
```

Comment: Remove `e.preventDefault();` and use `$('#pause')` instead of `$('.pause')` check http://jsfiddle.net/zrNV5/61/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

Your selectors are wrong:
`$('.pause')` should either be `$("#pause")` or `$(".rad")`

Also, you are calling `e.preventDefault()` inside `click`. This is preventing the default behavior of a click on a radio button, which is to check it.

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xoawg273/2/) for what I *think* you're trying to achieve, which is to let the radio buttons be a toggle for your timer:

```
var output = $('h1');
var isPaused = false;
var time = 30;
var t = window.setInterval(function() {

    if(!isPaused) {
        time--;
        output.text("0:" + time);
    }
}, 1000);

//with jquery
$('#pause').on('click', function(e) {
    isPaused = true;
});

$('#play').on('click', function(e) {
    isPaused = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type=radio]").change(function(){

   if(this.checked) 
   {
     alert("checked");
   }

});
```

And if your radio button has id say `play` then directly use `#play` as selector i.e. `$("#play").change()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="play" class="rad" type='radio' name='a' value="1"/>
    <input id="pause" class="rad" type='radio' name='a' value="2"/>

var output = $('h1');
var isPaused = false;
var time = 30;
var t = window.setInterval(function() {
    if(!isPaused) {
        time--;
        output.text("0:" + time);
    }
}, 1000);

//with jquery
$('.rad').on('change', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(this.value=='2')
    isPaused = true;
    else
        isPaused = false;
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zrNV5/62/)